# How do I make Compojure listen to a single IP

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have started a Compojure (Jetty) server with:

```
(defonce *server* (run-server {:host "localhost" :port 8080} "/*" (servlet routes)))
```

but netstat still shows that it is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, i.e. all IPs.

What is the correct parameter to pass to run-server to make it listen on a single IP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're going to have to patch Compojure.  It's not doing anything with your `:host` parameter.  Making this change to `server/jetty.clj` seems to work, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
(defn- create-server
  "Construct a Jetty Server instance."
  [options servlets]
  (let [port     (options :port 80)
        host     (options :host "0.0.0.0")
        connector (doto (org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.)
                    (.setPort port)
                    (.setHost host))
        server   (doto (Server.)
                   (.addConnector connector))
        servlets (partition 2 servlets)]
    (when (or (options :ssl) (options :ssl-port))
      (add-ssl-connector! server options))
    (doseq [[url-or-path servlet] servlets]
      (add-servlet! server url-or-path servlet))
    server))
```

```
user> (run-server {:port 12346})
2009-07-22 13:48:53.999::INFO:  jetty-6.1.15
2009-07-22 13:48:54.002::INFO:  Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:12346
nil
user> (run-server {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 12345})
2009-07-22 13:48:08.061::INFO:  jetty-6.1.15
2009-07-22 13:48:08.129::INFO:  Started SocketConnector@127.0.0.1:12345
```

Comment: This has now been rolled into compojure, so that it just works - yay open source !